# How do i merge elements in a list together?

Tags: python, list

I have this list of sentences and I want to merge them together to create one whole list.

```
test = [['Hello my name is Py. How are you today?'],['The world is a great place. Another sentence.']]
```

How do I merge the elements to create this?

```
test = ['Hello my name is Py. How are you today? The world is a great place. Another sentence.']
```

or

```
test = 'Hello my name is Py. How are you today? The world is a great place. Another sentence.'
```

Thanks

Comment: Why have each string in its own sub list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to chain the element from each sublist, calling str.join on the chain object to create a single string.

```
test = [['Hello my name is Py. How are you today?'],['The world is a great place. Another sentence.']]

from itertools import chain

print(" ".join(chain.from_iterable(test)))
Hello my name is Py. How are you today? The world is a great place. Another sentence
```

Or just using join:

```
print(" ".join(["".join(sub) for sub in test]))
Hello my name is Py. How are you today? The world is a great place. Another sentence.
```

If you only have a single sting in each sublist just index:

```
print(" ".join([sub[0] for sub in test]))

Hello my name is Py. How are you today? The world is a great place. Another sentence.
```

To get a list just wrap the join in a list:

```
print([" ".join([sub[0] for sub in test])])
['Hello my name is Py. How are you today? The world is a great place. Another sentence.']
```

If you have a lot of substrings in each sublist then chain will be the most efficient solution.

Comment: @marmeladze, yep, for multiple substrings it would be the most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> test = [['Hello my name is Py. How are you today?'],
...         ['The world is a great place. Another sentence.']]
>>>
>>> print '\n'.join(a for b in test for a in b)
Hello my name is Py. How are you today?
The world is a great place. Another sentence.

>>>
>>> print ' '.join(a for b in test for a in b)
Hello my name is Py. How are you today? The world is a great place. Another sentence.
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the lists, then join the strings:

```
' '.join(sum(test, []))
```

Demo:

```
>>> test = [['Hello my name is Py. How are you today?'],['The world is a great place. Another sentence.']]
>>> ' '.join(sum(test, []))
'Hello my name is Py. How are you today? The world is a great place. Another sentence.'
```

Warning: While this is neat and fine for a few lists, the more lists you have, the slower this gets:

```
>>> for n in (10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000):
        lists = [['Test'] for _ in range(n)]
        seconds = timeit(lambda: sum(lists, []), number=1)
        print('%10.7f' % seconds, 'seconds for', n, 'lists')


 0.0000109 seconds for 10 lists
 0.0001052 seconds for 100 lists
 0.0053068 seconds for 1000 lists
 0.5582595 seconds for 10000 lists
55.8725820 seconds for 100000 lists
```

Normal list comprehension is faster:

```
>>> for n in (10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000):
        lists = [['Test'] for _ in range(n)]
        seconds = timeit(lambda: [e for s in lists for e in s], number=1)
        print('%10.7f' % seconds, 'seconds for', n, 'lists')

 0.0000115 seconds for 10 lists
 0.0000327 seconds for 100 lists
 0.0002784 seconds for 1000 lists
 0.0024991 seconds for 10000 lists
 0.0228550 seconds for 100000 lists
```

Comment: I think it would be good to be more precise and say "sum the lists" instead of "join the lists," as `join()` will only handle strings and `sum()` refuses to concatenate strings.

Comment: Hmm... I think "join" is the more natural word. I'm not talking about the Python function names, I'm using the English word. And I did a google test now, there were about ten times as many results for "join two lists" than there were for "sum two lists". I'll switch to "concatenate" if you find that better, but I really don't want to say "sum" just because that's the name of the Python function I used.

Comment: "Join" is indeed a natural word, but when you use it to refer to `sum()`, it masks `join()`. :P Since I've gotten bitten in the past by trying to use `sum()` and `join()` as if they're interchangeable, I find it helpful to keep them mentally differentiated.

Comment: Ok, I don't want to be known as a masker, so I switched to "concatenate". And added a warning/test about the speed.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
test = [['Hello my name is Py. How are you today?'],['The world is a great place. Another sentence.']]
import itertools
print list(itertools.chain(*test))
```

Comment: It won't, it will create a list with multiple substrings not a single string

Answer (score -1):

to get list -

```
>>> test = ["".join([j  for j in i for i in test])]
>>> test
['The world is a great place. Another sentence.The world is a great place. Another sentence.']
```

string

```
>>> test = "".join([j  for j in i for i in test])
>>> test
'The world is a great place. Another sentence.The world is a great place. Another sentence.'
```

Comment: Your comprehensions are backwards.